# How to create data.php or data.xml file to attach with jquery for autocomplete

Tags: php, xml, autocomplete

I'm looking for a solution, I want to create a data file either using .php or .xml so that I can attach it with jquery for autocomplete. Can anyone please help me how to create data.php or data.xml?

I was insert data directly in jquery file within "semi-colon", but it takes long time to fetch data and I think its an inappropriate way to write code... Kindly tell me some solution that can increase speed of data search and how can I create data.php or data.xml file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var source = [
"3D ANIMATOR",
"ABATTOIR WORKER",
"ABLE SEAMAN",
"ABORIGINAL",
"ABRASIVE GRADER",
"ABRASIVE GRINDER",
"ABRASIVE MIXER",
"ABRASIVE SAWYER"];
$("#professions").autocomplete({
...
```

The above code is not complete but it is actually working according to my need, my actual problem was to make autocomplete with force user to select only given option, just like "Mustmatch" but this process is very slow while reading data and sometimes it does halt my browser. I have around 12000 of data that I want to attach with this autocomplete code.